# Does there exist a graph that the page ranks of each node are distinct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matrix-equations, page-rank

Suppose that there is a graph of $n$ nodes ($n>3$), is it possible that every node has a distinct page rank value?

the page rank is defined as $R$ while $MR=R$, $M$ is the transition matrix.

I have sampled one thousand random graph (10 nodes) and found no such graph, therefore I guess such graph does not exist. But I don't know how to prove this. Could someone give me some hints?

Comment: Good problem ($+1$).

Comment: I assume we are excluding graphs of infinite order.

Comment: @Graviton yes, it's of finite order.